# Nested Destructuring on Object Assignments

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, javascript-objects

With ES6 destructuring, is their any way to destructure nested objects on assignment?

Here is a quick code example to show what I mean:

```
let node = {
  ItemTitle: 'Title',
  ItemId: 5,
  Menu: {Item: [{ItemId: 579}]
}

 // my attempts
  let {
      ItemId: id,
      ItemTitle: title, 
      Menu['Item']: subItems
    } = node

  let {
      ItemId: id,
      ItemTitle: title, 
      Menu.Item: subItems
    } = node
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just repeat the same syntax for nested levels as with destructuring the top level:

**EDIT based on your comment**

> I need the object within the array

```js
let node = {
  ItemTitle: 'Title',
  ItemId: 5,
  Menu: {Item: [{ItemId: 579}]}
}

let {
  ItemId: id,       // extract `node.ItemId` into a variable called `id`
  ItemTitle: title, // extract `node.ItemTitle` into a variable called `title`
  Menu: {
    Item: [obj]     // extract `node.Menu.Item[0]` into a variable called obj
  }
} = node;

console.log('id =', id);
console.log('title =', title);
console.log('obj =', obj);
```

Pre-edit: Extracting the id of the object within the nested array.

```js
let node = {
  ItemTitle: 'Title',
  ItemId: 5,
  Menu: {Item: [{ItemId: 579}]}
}

let {
  ItemId: id,           // extract `node.ItemId` into a variable called `id`
  ItemTitle: title,     // extract `node.ItemTitle` into a variable called `title`
  Menu: {
    Item: [{ 
      ItemId: subItemId // extract `node.Menu.Item[0].ItemId` into a variable called `subItemId`
    }]  
  }
} = node;

console.log('id =', id);
console.log('title =', title);
console.log('subItemId =', subItemId);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I understand better now. If you check my example though, node.Menu.Item is an array. How do I destructure an array property of an object?

Comment: What part of the array do you need, the object within the array or the `ItemId` property of that object?

Comment: Thank you, I need the object within the array.

Comment: Excellent, thank you very much for making this so clear to me.

Comment: @rm-rf no problem amigo, glad to help out :)

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can do nested destructuring with ES6. [MDN gives you a nice example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#Nested_object_and_array_destructuring).

```js
let node = {
  ItemTitle: 'Title',
  ItemId: 5,
  Menu: {
    Item: [{
      ItemId: 579
    }]
  }
}

let { Menu: { Item: [{ ItemId }] } } = node

console.log(ItemId) // 579
```